# Rails "form_for" action, how redirect to a different path depending of kind of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, devise, form-for

I am using Devise as my authentication on a Rails app.

The User form works fine, but I want it to redirect to a different path depending on where the person starts on the site.

So all people (customers, contractors) are Users. But if you sign up to apply to be a new Contractor I want to send you to the new application form. If you are a customer you need to go to a different page with a different form.

I am new(again) to Rails and can not figure out how to do this. Is it something I can change in "form_for" directly in the view or something that needs to be done in the controller.

UPDATE:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: new_contrator_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

ERROR: 
undefined method `new_contrator_path' for #<#:0x007f88834bec28>

I am sure I am screwing up something in a controller...

2nd UPDATE
I am using this with 'scout_app' as the hidden field

```
<%= f.hidden_field :type, value: "scout_app" %>
```

This is what I have in the new user form but I can't get it to pass the attribute to the User. It always has NIL

Answer (score 4):

You can use the url parameter in form_for.

For example:

```
<%= form_for(@post, url: custom_path) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: I know I am probably asking really simple questions but if I try to do URL: contractor_path it causes an error. I am sure because I am introducing a new resource. Could you give me an example of a custom_path.

Comment: Could you show me the error, the routes for the contractors controller, and the form_for line?

Also, don't hesitate to check the documentation for form_for: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: Put an update in my original questions. Thanks again.

Comment: You used new_contrator_path, not new_contraCtor_path :)

Comment: Sorry ridiculous mistake, now it takes me to this http://localhost:3000/contractors/new.user which then says No route matches [POST] "/contractors/new.user" Passing that resource is a problem I guess. The weird thing is even if I don't try and pass that resource it goes to contractors/new.user

Comment: My bad, I was too focused on the typo to see the bigger problem. You specify `new_contractor_path(resource_name)` as the `url`. But this is the route for the NEW action in your contractors controller. What you want to do is specify the route for the CREATE action. Use `<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: contractors_path) do |f| %>` instead. You can see the path helpers for all your routes typing `rake routes` in your shell (the helper names are in the left column). Take a look at this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for more information about routes!

Comment: In my process I want to do two things, one: create a new user, then two send them to the form for new contractor. So first page is just email and password, once that submitted then go to the new contractors form. Am I on the right track to do that? It seems like it shouldn't be this complicated. When I use contractors_path it gets much closer but it is try to create a new contractor rather than a new user. Maybe I need to Icicle above recommended and have this happen after the fact instead?

Comment: Yes, use @Icicle method which will allow you to redirect the user (after he/she signed in) to the form for the new contractor. Then in this form, use `url: contractors_path` as mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Great, I appreciate all your help and time. I still learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can override default sign_in method of devise and redirect as per your requirement in your application_controller.rb file

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    # your code
  end
```

Comment: I thought about doing this, but I am a little lost on how it would know which page the sign up came from. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you pass some hidden param which can help you to know the type of page?

Comment: Hi I am trying to do what you suggested and updated my question above to show you the issue I am having now.

Comment: Ideally you should get value, can you try once with hidden_field_tag?